# Can the one-sided Laplacian transform be generalized to the distribution?

Tags: laplace-transform

My problem is that the one-sided Laplace transform I've encountered goes something like this.
$$\int_0^{+\infty}f(t)e^{-st}dt$$
But I think it is against the strict definition of the generalized function that the lower bound of the integral of the unilateral Laplace transformation is 0 instead of negative infinity? Would it be more reasonable to define the unilateral laplace transform by Fourier transform as follows?
$$\mathscr{L}T={\mathscr F}\{H(x)T(x)e^{-\sigma x}\}$$
$H(x)$ is Heaviside step funtion.
I mainly want to know whether this formula is the definition of unilateral Laplace transformation under generalized functions

Comment: note that you cannot multiply a general distribution by $H$; on the other hand, if you ask your distribution to have support in $[0,\infty)$, the trouble with the lower bound goes away (you still need to assume a reasonable behavior at $\infty$)

Comment: The Fourier transform is related to the bilateral Laplace transform (see [Relationship between Fourier and bilateral Laplace transforms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_transform#Fourier_transform).

Comment: @user8268 Oh,I see. $H$ is not $C^{\infty}$.Thanks for your help.